# Identifying dataframe columns by their first few characters

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in which the column names begin with certain characters:

```
> colnames(df)
[1] "p.crossfencing"  "p.livestockdrinking"  "v.livestocktrail"
[5] "v.landclearing"  "v.grazelivestock"     "v.useequipment"
```

Etc...

I'd like to select columns based on the first few characters (for example, those column names that begin with `"v."`) Basically, I'm trying do the same thing that `ls(pattern="")` does for objects, but in my case, for column names within a dataframe.

EDIT: Answer by Thomas below put me on the right path. I needed to use:

```
j[grep("^v.",j)]
```

where `j <- colnames(df)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for `df[,grep("^v.",names(df))]`?

Comment: That almost does what I needed - enough to help me figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also write something as below:

```
df[, (grep(x = colnames(df), pattern = "^v."))]
```